# Direct Server Return software and configuration for mesh network of raspbery pi servers

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, cdn, transparent-proxy

I don't know much about DSR technology but as I am aware both load balancer and servers need to be behind same router because of virtual IP addresses.

I need solution to have cloud-based geo-based load balancers which will receive request with some geoDNS service but i want them to just be transparent proxy with some software which will be used as discovery for mesh network of active raspberry pi (or any other low power SCB device) and only proxy request to device which will directly return response without any bandwidth proxying through load balancers.

Is this even possible as a real life solution?

Thanks.